# Azure DevOps Kanban Board Item Test Annotations have stopped appearing, I think I broke it and need suggestions how to fix it

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps Kanban Board Item Test Annotations have stopped appearing, I think I broke it and need suggestions how to fix it.

Here is an example of a working one.
[image: Working Item for reference]

We have some number that absolutely have Test Cases that were added to the card and are in Test Suites and are linked to the relevant work item as "Tested By".  However, on some of these items the Test Annotation simply doesn't show up.  (Making it hard to find the correct Test Suite and impacting the usefulness of the board to our QA team)

With "New Boards Hubs" turned on NO annotations appear at all.  With it off only SOME of the Test Annotation ones are missing.

I expect the Test Annotations to appear on the cards as they have for the last 5 years.

We had this issue back in 2019 for a while.  Our Dev Manager found a section of config UI that gave us an error message with specific items that had "Circular links" we resolved those specific items and the issue went away.

Looking through all config pages I was not able to find this error this time around.

So, looking over MS documentation in current day suggested the same circular linking issue. I hunted down ALL links between items of the same hierarchical level and made sure they weren't "Parent/Child" links but instead "Related" links.

This did not resolve the issue, I checked on 3 separate occasions to make sure I hadn't missed any links.

I posted to MS on the Developer Community and got a "Sorry, but we cannot reproduce the issue nor are we getting any other reports of a problem. We will keep an eye on things and re-open if needed."

- **2019 Item**
  Azure DevOps - Kanban Board - Test Case Bottle not always showing
  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-DevOps---Kanban-Board---Test-Case/761565?sort=newest&scope=follow
- **2023 Item**
  Test Annotation on Kanban Board items are breaking all board item annotations (Test Bottle is missing)
  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Test-Annotation-on-Kanban-Board-items-ar/10347193

Comment: My guess would be the iteration for the test case is not enabled for the team or the area/iteration of the card isn't assigned to the team.

Comment: Just check, all iterations on the board (2 of them at this time) are enabled and assigned to the team.  

Of note, the items that don't show the test annotation are not exclusive to either iteration.